# Trying to set the row height in a tableView for the cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm updating an app of mine, and I have used this method in other areas of the app and it works, but for some reason, it's not working on a tableView.

The tableView is inside of a ViewController (CurrencyViewController)

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

tableView.dataSource = self

extension CurrencyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currencies.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currencyCell")! as! CurrencyTableViewCell

        cell.name.text = currencies[indexPath.row].currencyName
        cell.name.textColor = Styles.whiteColor()
        cell.symbol.text = currencies[indexPath.row].currencyCode
        cell.symbol.textColor = Styles.whiteColor()

        cell.backgroundColor = Styles.mainColor();

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

The tableView itself works, it's just not updating the height of the row.

Did something change with the update of Swift?

Comment: Yes Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the tableview?

Comment: yes, the delegate is set. Everything is working, just for some reason, the height isn't being rendered.

Comment: @icekomo your code only shows `dataSource = self`, where is delegate set?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the line that says `return 200.0` and verify it's being executed.

Comment: @Rakesha, is that what you meant?

Comment: Have you conformed to the `UITableViewDelegate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have conformed to the `UITableViewDelegate` ?

```
extension CurrencyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Answer (score 1):

If `dataSource` (and `delegate`) is connected in IB delete

<strike>`tableView.dataSource = self`</strike>

You must also adopt `UITableViewDelegate` in the extension, connecting the delegate is not sufficient

```
extension CurrencyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```